# Change storage path in Lumen when running tests with Codeception

Tags: php, laravel, codeception, lumen

In Lumen 5.4, I want to override the default storage path, and since the use of `useStoragePath()` [as possible with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36566710/938297) seems unavailable in Lumen, I went for another solution by [defining the `storage_path()` function before it gets defined by the framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38386618/938297).

This requires a modification to the `bootstrap/app.php` file, which works perfectly fine in normal operation:

```
// App helpers
require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/helpers.php';

// Composer autoloader
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

However, when running tests using Codeception, it loads the `vendor/autoload.php` before `bootstrap/app.php` gets loaded, which results in this obvious fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare storage_path() (previously declared in vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\helpers.php:308) in app\helpers.php

I tried extending the shipped *Lumen* module in Codeception, overwriting the `registerAutoloaders()` method, without luck (which makes sense, as Codeception also needs to include the Composer autoloader):

```
class App extends \Codeception\Module\Lumen
{
    protected function registerAutoloaders()
    {
        // Don't include autoload file here, as it will be required in the apps bootstrap file
    }
}
```

The default `storage_path()` in Lumen has no entry points for extensions afaik:

```
public function storagePath($path = '')
{
    return $this->basePath().'/storage'.($path ? '/'.$path : $path);
}
```

How can I change the default storage path in Lumen which also plays nice when running tests in Codeception?

Comment: An obvious solution would be to just use the default `storage_path()` implementation when running tests. I would still be curious however for a possible workaround using a modified storage path in tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your helpers.php to the composer.json's `autoload` section so that it will be auto loaded.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: That's actually a good suggestion. Unfortunately, Composer prioritises vendor autoloaders first, and since the Lumen `helpers.php` is also loaded using the same method, this file is included first hence giving the same results.